# Angular Error: [$injector:modulerr] 1.4.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I get an injector:modulerr error in a basic MEAN app...

Here is my home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="jobs">
  <head>
    <title>GA Jobs</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="/javascripts/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="time-slot" ng-controller="JobsController">

      <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="/upload" method="/post">
        <select>
          <option value="hit_list">Hit List</option>
          <option value="contact">Contact</option>
          <option value="engagement">Engagement</option>
          <option value="hired">Hired</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" ng-model="company" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Company">
        <input type="text" ng-model="contact" class="form-control" name="contact" id="contact" placeholder="Contact">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
      </form>

      <h1>this is home.html</h1>
      <h1>{{company}}</h1>
      <h1>{{contact}}</h1>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

here is my main.js:

```
var app = angular.module('jobs',['ngRoute'])

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'JobsController'
    })
})

app.controller('JobsController',
function($scope, $stateParams, posts){

});
```

Does this have something to do with having a server-router as well and ejs files in the view? I'm confused on how the client-side angular router works with the node server-side router. please help.

Comment: Can you paste the error message in the question?

Comment: You are loading `angular-ui-router.js` instead of `angular-router.js`.

Comment: You're referencing ui-router in the index.html, but are using the ngRouter. Replace $routeProvider with $urlRouterProvider and use $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

Answer (score 1):

The app is unable to load the `ngRoute` module. `ngRoute` has been moved to its own module and is no longer part of the core.

You'll need to include the `angular-route` module to use `ngRoute`. You should replace this line:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

with this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: or update config to use `ui-router` which is much more robust